# How can I specify a profile for EmrCreateJobFlowOperator?

Tags: python, airflow, boto3, amazon-emr

I am creating an EMR cluster with EmrCreateJobFlowOperator, but I need to specify a profile for it to find the role "EMR_EC2_DefaultRole". The following code works with "aws_default" if I set my profile configuration in "~/.aws/config" into the default profile, but this is something I do not wish to do since I have many different profiles and the default one should be clean. Is there any work around?

The right roles are configured for my profile but not for the default one, which is very basic:

```
aws iam list-roles --profile my_specific_profile | grep 'EMR_DefaultRole\|EMR_EC2_DefaultRole'
```

This works only if I change the default profile in "~/.aws/config".

```
create_emr_cluster = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
    task_id="create_emr_cluster",
    job_flow_overrides=job_flow_overrides,
    aws_conn_id="aws_default",
    emr_conn_id="emr_default",
    region_name="my_region",
    dag=dag,
)
```

To avoid changing my "~/.aws/config", I have also tried the following without success:

```
create_emr_cluster = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
    task_id="create_emr_cluster",
    job_flow_overrides=job_flow_overrides,
    aws_conn_id="aws_default",
    emr_conn_id="emr_default",
    region_name="my_region",
    profile_name="my_specific_profile",
    dag=dag,
)
```

and

```
create_emr_cluster = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
    task_id="create_emr_cluster",
    job_flow_overrides=job_flow_overrides,
    aws_conn_id="aws_default",
    emr_conn_id="emr_default",
    region_name="my_region",
    dag=dag,
)

boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name="my_specific_profile")
```

and

```
create_emr_cluster = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
    task_id="create_emr_cluster",
    job_flow_overrides=job_flow_overrides,
    aws_conn_id="my_specific_profile",
    emr_conn_id="emr_default",
    region_name="my_region",
    dag=dag,
)
```

Error is:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the RunJobFlow operation: Invalid InstanceProfile: EMR_EC2_DefaultRole.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is simple. In fact I just have to set the default profile by adding the following command before the code that creates the cluster:

```
os.environ["AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE"] = "my_specific_profile"
```

Comment: Can I achieve the above without setting an environ var? Like using the boto3.client with EmrCreateJobFlowOperator?